# Displaying a Data Window on nativescript-ui-pro

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I have a list of objects that represent points in a line chart that grows as data is fetched and can exceed more than 20,000 (twenty thousand) objects.

But the graph can only display 1000 points at a time, for this I did the following function:

```
private pointPush(model: ViewModel, data: Point[]) {
  model.values.push(...data);
    if (model.values.length > 1000) {
      model.values.splice(0, model.values.length - 1000);
    }
}
```

but I realize that when it exceeds 1000 points it gets very slow, because I think that internally the `splice` function created a new array.

You can do something similar to a buffer ring that has a constant size but the data access pointer will spin as new data is added overwriting older ones.

Remembering that I'm using an ObservableArray with nativescript-ui.

Comment: if model.values can be over 20,000 in length, doing `model.values.splice(0, model.values.length - 1000);` will use 19,000, you would need to use `model.values.splice(0, 1000);` to only select a thousand

Comment: I need show only 1000, of 19.000 itens, this way it is working, but slow, I need other method more efficient, because I remove extra itens where I put news, if I put 2000 new itens it remove 2000 itens and not show the first new 1000 itens, the ideal maning is a windows like Buffer Array. if not yet exist one, I showld create a new class for this.

Comment: but the code you posted will take 19000 items, not 1000

Comment: length = 20000 =>
20000-1000 = 19000 =>
splice(0,19000) of 20000 = 1000 itens